# React router auth control, how to handle session end?

Tags: reactjs, session, authentication, react-router

So I have read few methods how to do that, the first one is using **onEnter** mehods on route and the second one is having an higher component (like this example https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1)

So my question here is not about state management but about state update, let me explain.

1. I login successfully , my state is updated, and know I can access the '/settings' route.
   (1'. If I logout state is update and I can't access ...)

My question is how should I handle properly session end ?

The login state is saying I'm still connected but meanwhile the session has expired. So it means I can access the '/settings' page because has not been updated. What should I do ? I see two options:

1. I send a request to my server each time I want to access a protected route so it will update the state accordingly.
2. I let the user go to '/settings' but when he tries to perform an action I check on server side if the session is still valid and send him to the login page in case the session has expired.

I hope it's clear, what do you think the better option is ? I would go for the option 2. but I'm not 100% sure

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer for your use case: go with option 1.

Explanation: Imagine you click on "Settings" and and maybe all the settings are loaded from the store. Now, displaying all these settings is fine, but what if you want to update something? You probably make changes or even fill out some text fields, only to get informed that your session has timed out and you need to re-authenticate in order for your settings to be updated/saved. Also, what if the user is using a shared/public client and forgets to log out? All settings will still be displayed, even when the session has long timed out. And to make it even worse, just think of the additional effort required for effectively caching actions made / information added by the user that have to be replayed once re-authentication took place.

So in order to not discourage your users and for security reasons, go with option 1 and make sure the session is still valid BEFORE you render a protected resource.

This can be done in many ways, for example sending a timeout value with your token and check the value on client side (not very secure, since everything stored on the client can be altered on the client), send a verification request to your API using middleware or HoCs before rendering, a combination of both et cetera.